# Return nil struct instead of empty struct go-gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

With the following model:

```
type User struct {
    UUID string         `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name string         `gorm:"NOT NULL"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```

If you do the following query with go-gorm for a user that does **NOT** exist:

```
var user User
db.First(&user)
```

You end up receiving an empty struct with the date fields populated. Is there a way to instead just receive a `nil` struct back or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Pretty sure that if you use pointers for your time fields they will be returned nil if they aren't set, and returned properly if they are :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In gorm you are supposed to check if the record is empty, with a method call:

```
if db.First(&user, 77).RecordNotFound() {
    log.Println("UUID:", 77, err)
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, thought I was going about this the wrong way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With this model

```golang
type User struct {
    UUID string         `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name string         `gorm:"NOT NULL"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```

- you can try this for getting nil pointer

```golang
var user *User
db.First(&user)
```

- or else you can use this also

```golang
var user User
if db.First(&user).RecordNotFound(){
  //record not found
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a Pointer function

```
func (user User) Pointer() *User {
    var t time.Time
    if user.UUID == "" && user.Name == "" && user.CreatedAt == t && user.UpdatedAt == t {
        return nil
    }
    return &user
}
```

and pass it

```
var user User
db.First(user.Pointer())
```

Comment: that's not the way you handle errors, gorm provides a method call to look if record is not found.